# Control query is not correct in DotNet

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading, invoke

Please help, I receive an error "Cannot invoke because object is nothing". But I've added a query to ask if object is nothing. Visual Studio still goes into the routine.

[image: Form is nothing]

```
Private WithEvents frm As frmFullScreen

 Private Sub UpdateImageInGuiAsync(ByVal bm As System.Drawing.Bitmap)


        If Me.frm.InvokeRequired = True Then
            Dim dl As New BitmapDelegate(AddressOf UpdateImageInGuiGuiThread)
            If Me.frm IsNot Nothing Then Me.frm.Invoke(dl, bm)
        Else
            Call Me.UpdateImageInGuiGuiThread(bm)
        End If

    End Sub
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Regards

Comment: What is `frm`? Where is it declared? How are you initializing it? What sub is the code erroring on? Where is the sub called from?

Comment: frm Is System.Windows.Forms.Form (without anything on it). frm = new Form1. The Sub is called UpdateImage(bitmap). It is called from parent.

Comment: When is it called? After exiting from the `Form1` form?

Comment: the methode is called, lets say, every 1 second. But user can close the `frm` and on next call the methode should exit with next incomming image. But debugger does not show correct informations or does not calculate or even I need to add something to catch this fault.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your form is disposing?

If so, I'd just wrap the entire if block in a try/catch.

Comment: I would say this is an exceptional instance myself and just handle it.